# How to Print, when columns have spaces - awk?

Tags: linux, bash, grep, awk

Problem:
desired columns have text with spaces  `SAMSUNG MZNLN128HCGR-000H1`
undesired columns have text with spaces, see `VENDOR` = `M.2 SSD`
awk only printing the first word.
awk not printing the column of data.

`lsblk -S |grep "MODEL\|SERIAL\|sdc"`

```
NAME HCTL       TYPE VENDOR   MODEL                          REV SERIAL               TRAN
sdc  8:0:0:0    disk M.2 SSD  SAMSUNG MZNLN128HCGR-000H1    1.00 S206NX0H510879       usb
```

.

`lsblk -S |grep "sdc"`

```
sdc  8:0:0:0    disk M.2 SSD  SAMSUNG MZNLN128HCGR-000H1    1.00 S206NX0H510879       usb
```

.

Does Field separator = tab or space?
`*` replaces space
`&` replaces tab
`lsblk -S |grep "sdc" |tr " " "*" |tr "\t" "&"   #replace with * &`

```
sdc**8:0:0:0****disk*M.2*SSD**SAMSUNG*MZNLN128HCGR-000H1****1.00*S206NX0H510879*******usb
```

.

undesired output:

````
lsblk -S |grep "$d2d" |awk '{$1=""; $2=""; $3=""; $4=""; $5=""; print;}'```
SAMSUNG MZNLN128HCGR-000H1 1.00 S206NX0H520889 usb
````

.

How to get desired output of
 `MODEL` column and
`SERIAL` column?

```
SAMSUNG MZNLN128HCGR-000H1 S206NX0H510879
```

.

using:
`neofetch --stdout |grep 'OS:'`
OS: Kubuntu 22.04.3 LTS x86_64

`awk -W version`
mawk 1.3.4 20200120 ...

--

Answer (score 4):

> How to get desired output of
> MODEL column and
> SERIAL column?

Use `lsblk -o` to specify which columns you want it to output (together with `-n` to suppress the headings), and `lsblk <dev>` to specify which device to output information about (generally together with `-d` to disable outputting child devices).

```
> lsblk -d -n -o MODEL,SERIAL /dev/sdc
ST6000VN001-2BB186 ZCT2X6FK
```

When custom formatting is needed, use `lsblk -J` for JSON output together with `jq` or another JSON formatter:

```
> lsblk -J -S | jq -r '.blockdevices[] | "\(.model), s/n. \(.serial)"'
Samsung SSD 870 EVO 2TB, s/n. S6PPNX0W312382K
Samsung SSD 870 EVO 2TB, s/n. S6PPNX0W312387C
ST6000VN001-2BB186, s/n. ZCT2X6FK
ST6000VN001-2BB186, s/n. ZCT2WNZY
```

So if you really want to involve awk, this is how you would define a *custom* field separator that (hopefully) doesn't conflict with regular output:

```
> lsblk -J -S \
          | jq -r '.blockdevices[] | join(";")' \
          | awk -F';' '{print $5 ", s/n. " $6}'
Samsung SSD 870 EVO 2TB, s/n. S6PPNX0W312382K
Samsung SSD 870 EVO 2TB, s/n. S6PPNX0W312387C
ST6000VN001-2BB186, s/n. ZCT2X6FK
ST6000VN001-2BB186, s/n. ZCT2WNZY
```

If you want specific fields, you could do it in two ways – either combine `-J` with the same `-o` (and usually `-d`) that was mentioned earlier, *or* use jq to select specific fields:

```
> lsblk -J -d -o MODEL,SERIAL | jq -r '.blockdevices[] | join(";")'
```

```
> lsblk -J -S | jq -r '.blockdevices[] | [.model, .serial] | join(";")'
```